# Отмена автоматического выделения сообщения на ответ в тг боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

После полного завершения диалога с ботом в беседе телеграмм сообщение от бота автоматически выделяется на ответ, как это исправить

```
def screenshot_request(message, bot, problem, userstate, buttons):
    if message.text.lower() == 'да':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отлично! Отправьте фото скриншота:')
        bot.set_state(message.from_user.id, userstate.with_screen, message.chat.id)
    elif message.text.lower() == 'нет':
        problem_message = '\n'.join(
            [f"{key}: {value}" for key, value in problem.items()])
        markup = buttons()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, problem_message)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отправить обращение?', reply_markup=markup, disable_notification=True,
                         reply_to_message_id=None)
        bot.set_state(message.from_user.id, userstate.confirm_without_screen, message.chat.id)
    else:
        markup = buttons()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'К сожалению я вас не понял(( Я ожидаю ответ да/нет. '
                                          'У вас есть скриншот?', reply_markup=markup, disable_notification=True)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно ли как-то убрать выделение сообщения на ответ?

Comment: Ну или можно попробовать использовать selective, но я не знаю как

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, вы не приложили фрагмент кода, который визуализирован на скриншоте.
Метод `ForceReply` как раз отвечает за цитирование сообщений бота:

При получении сообщения с этим объектом клиенты Telegram отобразят пользователю интерфейс ответа (действуйте так, как если бы пользователь выбрал сообщение бота и нажал "Ответить"). Это может быть чрезвычайно полезно, если вы хотите создать удобные пошаговые интерфейсы без необходимости жертвовать режимом конфиденциальности.

Подробнее в [документации Telegram](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#forcereply). Найдите этот элемент и отключите его.